# Fake Step Data for Apple Health Kit in React Native Development

Tags: ios, react-native, healthkit

I'm developing a React-Native app that utilizes Apple Health-Kit to gather daily step data for users. I've got everything setup and running, but I'm not sure what people are doing to provide fake step data for testing/development purposes. For the other parts of my app, I'm always getting data from HTTP requests, for which I just provide a test api and serve up dummy data from a file in my repo. But does anyone know how to do this for step data (or any other sort of data) in Apple Health-Kit?

Thanks

Comment: are you using an open source library to access the healthkit data? I'm curious because I'm looking at the options

Comment: I was using "React-Native Apple Health Kit", but it was abandoned so I ended up forking it and building it out myself a little bit more. I'm not sure if there is a current good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to handle this. Newer versions of the Xcode iPhone simulator come with Apple Health Kit installed. So, you can just manually go into the app in the simulator and add some step data the old fashioned way. Not a scalable solution if you need loads of data, but good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add step data via the Health app already included on your iPhone simulator.